# Stripe paymentMethods.retrieve not returning a value for a connected account

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I'm trying to retrieve the information for a single payment method object on my connected stripe account. However, my response is simply an empty string. I know the payment method id exists because I'm able to get all the payment methods for a customer via customers.listPaymentMethods. Any thoughts? My backend call and response are below:

```
const paymentMethod = await stripe.paymentMethods.retrieve(
        [PAYMENT_METHOD_ID],
        {
          stripeAccount: [CONNECTED_ACCOUNT_ID],
        }
      );
```

[image]

Comment: First thing you'd want to check is if you're sending request using the correct API keys. Then you can check if the connected account ID is correct. The response you shared seems to be coming from your own server (not directly from the API), so you'd also want to check if there's any logic in your server-side code that filters through the API response.

Comment: The keys are correct as other calls are successful, and my server endpoint has no logic other than calling stripe’s method. My server returns the object returned by stripe per the docs.